# Unable to validate json webtoken

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, express-jwt

I have made a route to create a post which i want to link to the logged in user.

```
router.post(
  "/create-post",
  jwt({ secret: "bRgRAnUUuk", algorithms: ["HS256"] }),
  function (req, res) {
    if (!req.auth.admin) return res.sendStatus(401);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  },
  createPost
);
```

This is the actual createPost controller:

```
exports.createPost = (req, res) => {
  try {
    let post = new Post({ content, postedBy: req.user._id });
    post.save();
    res.json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

My user is logged in with a token.

[image]

Here is my post request:

```
const [userObj, setUserObj] = useContext(UserContext);

  const submitPost = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userObj.token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        content: value,
      }),
    };

    const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/create-post",
      requestOptions
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
      throw new Error(message);
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    setValue("");
  };
```

However whenever i try to create a post i get a 401 error. No token found.
I'm not sure where to start with this error. Any help would be great! Thanks ;)

Comment: Did you add the JWT to the request `Authorization` header when sending the HTTP request?

Comment: No, i definitely did forget that. Thank you!

Comment: It did not work unfortunately. I added the post request to the question.

Comment: Can you ensure that you're receiving it at the API side of things? And also test that the jwt is correctly generated through jwt.io.

Comment: What's `req.auth`? Check it using `console.log(req.auth)`, I guess there is no `admin` property

Comment: req.auth gives me back the following: ```{ _id: '64a569a210d5aedcc055bddb', iat: 1689227257, exp: 1689832057 }```

Comment: It is working now! I made a few changes but it's all working. Thank you very much for your help!